# Opencv face detection webcam is not saving detected faces

Tags: python, opencv, face-detection

Im using opencv to detect faces in my webcam and whenever a face is detected I want to crop the ROI of face and save its image locally on my system. But when I run the code it doesnt do anything at all.
My webcam is working in opencv(which Ive already tested). But this specific code isnt working, for unknown reasons.

```
import os
import cv2

ctr=0
# import face detection cascade
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('/home/opi/opencv-3.3.0/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
# create capture object
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)


while(True):
    # capture frame-by-frame
    ret, img = cap.read()
    # convert image to grayscale
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(img, 1.3, 5)
    # for each face draw a rectangle around and copy the face

    for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
        roi_color = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        roi_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        #SAVE THE DETECTED FACES LOCALLY
        roi_gray=cv2.resize(roi_gray,(100,100))
        cv2.imwrite('faces'+'/'+str(ctr)+'.jpg',roi_gray)
        ctr+=1
    # display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('frame',img)


# when everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

When I kill the code pressing Ctrl+C, I can see this error which also doesnt make much sense :-

```
opi@admin:~$ python input.py
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "input.py", line 18, in <module>
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(img, 1.3, 5)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Answer (score 0):

You have forgotten to add `cv2.waitKey(1)` and that is why your code crashes while it is in an infinite loop  ( `while True: ...` ). We can also say that there is no time for showing(refreshing) frames ...

Add this block of code:

```
# display the resulting frame
cv2.imshow('frame',img)

key = cv2.waitKey(1)
if key == 32: # if the space key is pressed
    break
```

The final code :

```
import os
import cv2

ctr=0
# import face detection cascade
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('/home/opi/opencv-3.3.0/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
# create capture object
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)


while True:
    # capture frame-by-frame
    ret, img = cap.read()
    # convert image to grayscale
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(img, 1.3, 5)
    # for each face draw a rectangle around and copy the face

    for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
        roi_color = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        roi_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        #SAVE THE DETECTED FACES LOCALLY
        roi_gray=cv2.resize(roi_gray,(100,100))
        cv2.imwrite('faces'+'/'+str(ctr)+'.jpg',roi_gray)
        ctr+=1
    # display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('frame',img)

    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if key == 32: # if space key is pressed
        break


# when everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```